# Prove Set is disjoint

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

If $$n \in \mathbb{Z}, \geq3$$
$${A_{n}}=\left \{ {an+1: a \in \mathbb{Z}} \right \}$$

$${B_{n}}=\left \{ n|(b+1): b \in \mathbb{Z} \right \}$$

How do we prove that the set is disjoint? So This is easy to choose a number, an integer. Then I prove that An is not a subset of Bn and same time, Bn is not a subset of An. I think I need some help.

Comment: You need to show there is no element in $A_n \cap B_n$, or equivalently, there is no $m$ such that $m \in A_n $ and $m \in B_n$

Comment: $B_n$ should be written as $\{b\in\Bbb Z:n|(b+1)\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of $B_n$ does not make sense. If we interpret it as $B_n=\{b \in \mathbb Z: n|(b+1)\}$ then statement is correct: Suppose $m \in A_n \cap B_n$. Then $m=an+1$ and $m=kn-1$ for some integer $k$. But then  $(k-a)n=2$ which is  contradiction since $n$ divides then left hand side but not the right hand side.

Comment: I cannot parse the def'n of $B_n$ in the Q.

Answer (score 0):

All elements in $A_n$ are congruent to $1$ modulo $n$ and all elements in $B_n$ are of the form $b=kn-1,k\in\Bbb Z$, hence congruent  to $-1$ modulo $n$. For $n\ge3$, is $1\equiv-1$?